# Detecting GPU family 3 on iOS reliably at run time

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, metal, metalkit

I was using this function to detect A9 device or higher in the code:

```
    public static var gpuFamily3AndHigh:Bool = {
      return ARConfiguration.isSupported //Hack to know A9 or more
    }
```

But now Apple is rejecting the code since the app has no ARKit features. How do I identify it without using ARKit on both iOS 13 and iOS 12. On iOS 13, I see I can do:

```
  public static var gpuFamily3AndHigh:Bool = {
   // return ARConfiguration.isSupported //Hack to know A9 or more
    
    guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else { return false }
    
    return device.supportsFamily(.apple3)
}()
```

But I don't know if .apple3 is the right constant than .common3, and also what do I do on iOS 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/detecting_gpu_features_and_metal_software_versions) correctly, you should check for the supported family (as you do) when the API is available and fall back to checking for a specific feature set otherwise.

And if you really want to check for the A9 and above specifically, the family `.apple3` and the feature set `.iOS_GPUFamily3_v1` seem to be the way to go.